# VB.NET Preprocessor Directives

Tags: vb.net, preprocessor

Why doesn't `#IF Not DEBUG` work the way I'd expect in VB.NET?

```
#If DEBUG Then
   Console.WriteLine("Debug")
#End If

#If Not DEBUG Then
   Console.WriteLine("Not Debug")
#End If

#If DEBUG = False Then
   Console.WriteLine("Not Debug")
#End If
' Outputs: Debug, Not Debug
```

But, a manually set const does:

```
#Const D = True
#If D Then
   Console.WriteLine("D")
#End If

#If Not D Then
   Console.WriteLine("Not D")
#End If
' Outputs: D
```

And, of course, C# has the expected behavior as well:

```
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Debug");
#endif

#if !DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Not Debug");
#endif
// Outputs: Debug
```

Comment: Works fine for me, the first one displays just Debug in Debug mode and Not Debug, Not Debug in Release mode. Are you sure you don't have something "wierd" going on in your project settings?

Comment: Hmmm...I've tried it both with VS2008 in an existing ASP.NET project, and then Snippet Compiler. I'll try a new Console project and see what happens.

Comment: It was a new console app I tried.

Comment: Argh. A new console app works as expected. Now I'm really confused....

Comment: Odd. Sure someone hasn't messed around with the preprocessor settings for the project?

Comment: It's an ASP.NET website project, so it's compiled on demand. Snippet Compiler is also affected...the only thing I can think of is that it's an issue with the Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider (which, AFAIK, both ASP.NET and Snippet Compiler use instead of vbc.exe). Further investigation under way....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out, it's not *all* of VB.NET that's broken - just the CodeDomProvider (which both ASP.NET and Snippet Compiler use).

Given a simple source file:

```
Imports System
Public Module Module1
    Sub Main()
       #If DEBUG Then
          Console.WriteLine("Debug!")
       #End If

       #If Not DEBUG Then
          Console.WriteLine("Not Debug!")
       #End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

Compiling with vbc.exe version 9.0.30729.1 (.NET FX 3.5):

```
> vbc.exe default.vb /out:out.exe
> out.exe
  Not Debug!
```

That makes sense...I didn't define DEBUG, so it shows "Not Debug!".

```
> vbc.exe default.vb /out:out.exe /debug:full
> out.exe
  Not Debug!
```

And, using CodeDomProvider:

```
Using p = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("VisualBasic")
   Dim params As New CompilerParameters() With { _
      .GenerateExecutable = True, _
      .OutputAssembly = "out.exe" _
   }
   p.CompileAssemblyFromFile(params, "Default.vb")
End Using

> out.exe
Not Debug!
```

Okay, again - that makes sense. I didn't define DEBUG, so it shows "Not Debug". But, what if I include debug symbols?

```
Using p = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("VisualBasic")
   Dim params As New CompilerParameters() With { _
      .IncludeDebugInformation = True, _
      .GenerateExecutable = True, _
      .OutputAssembly = "C:\Users\brackett\Desktop\out.exe" _
   }
   p.CompileAssemblyFromFile(params, "Default.vb")
End Using

> out.exe
Debug!
Not Debug!
```

Hmm...I didn't define DEBUG, but maybe it defined it for me? But if it did, it must have defined it as "1" - because I can't get that behavior with any other value. ASP.NET, using the CodeDomProvider, [must define it the same way](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2005/12/01/2559.aspx).

Looks like the CodeDomProvider is tripping over VB.NET's stupid [psuedo-logical operators](http://www.nerdymusings.com/LPMArticle.asp?ID=16).

Moral of the story? `#If Not` is not a good idea for VB.NET.

---

And now that source is available, I can [verify that it does actually set it equal to 1](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/microsoft/visualbasic/VBCodeProvider.cs) as I expected:

```
if (options.IncludeDebugInformation) {
      sb.Append("/D:DEBUG=1 ");
      sb.Append("/debug+ ");
}
```